# removing a comma or semicolon from the end of a string if present -using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am getting a comma seperated or semicolon seperated string.
I want to remove the comma or the semicolon which may occur at the end of the string.

**e.g.a,b,c, should be converted to a,b,c**

a;b;c; should be converted to a;b;c

I want a javascript or regex expression which removes the comma (**,**) or the semi colon (**;**) only if it occurs otherwise the string should be left as it is.

please help

Comment: Java and JavaScript have **nothing** in common besides the "Java" in the name and some general syntax things such as curly brackets.

Answer (score 18):

### Solution

This can be solved simply with [regex <sup>MDN DOCs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) and [`.replace()` <sup>MDN DOCs</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```
your_string = your_string.replace(/[,;]$/,'');
```

Here is a jsfiddle that you can run to demo the code: http://jsfiddle.net/5eksE/1/

### What's happening

`/[,;]$/` is the regex portion of this script. The slashes can be ignored as they are just regex delimiters.

`[]` is a container for a range of values that you would like to match in this case `,;`.

`$` indicates the end of the string.

So putting it all together we are hunting for the comma or semi-colon that is right at the end of a string.

Comment: Can you make it complete for OP by adding the semicolon?

Comment: Here's a couple links that I always keep handy too.  http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html  http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 4):

Regex to handle both comma and semicolon

```
your_string = your_string.replace(/[,;]$/, "");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can check where a character occurs in a string using [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`lastIndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf). In your case, when `lastIndexOf()` returns an index that is equal to the length of string minus 1, then the index is for the last character in the string:

```
var index = input.lastIndexOf(";");
if(index == input.length - 1) 
{
  input = input.substring(0, input.length - 1);
}
```

Or, as a one liner:

```
input = input.lastIndexOf(";") == input.length - 1 ?  input.substring(0, input.length -1 ) : input;
```

Answer (score 1):

treffynnon's answer is correct. To elaborate a little, it just checks whether your string matches the regular expression `,$` (where $ indicates the end of the string), and if so, replaces the comma with an empty string. If you wanted to check for either a comma or a semicolon, you would just change it to

```
your_string = your_string.replace(/[,;]$/,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

I normally do

```
value = value.substring(0, value.length-1)
```

although I ensure that it is there in my previous loop. Sorry missed the second part of your question. You could put in a ternery

```
value = value.substring(0, (value[value.length-1] == ',') ? value.length -1 : value.length);
```

although it is not that elegant.